# Snowflake create table using the query result of another table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing an issue related to a project of mine. Here is the summary of what i would like to do :

I have a big daily file (100 Go) with the following extract (no header) :

```
ID_A|segment_1
ID_A|segment_2
ID_B|segment_2
ID_B|segment_3
ID_B|segment_4
ID_B|segment_5
ID_C|segment_1
ID_D|segment_2
ID_D|segment_4
```

Every ID (from A to D) can be linked to one or multiple segments (from 1 to 5).

I would like to process this file in order to have the following result (the result file contains a header) :

```
ID|segment_1|segment_2|segment_3|segment_4|segment_5
ID_A|1|1|0|0|0
ID_B|0|1|1|1|1
ID_C|1|0|0|0|0
ID_D|0|1|0|1|0
```

1 means that the ID is included in the segment, 0 means that it is not.

I am able to do it in Bigquery via the following script to get the result :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT id, ''' || (
  SELECT STRING_AGG("COUNTIF(segment = '" || segment || "') AS " || segment ORDER BY segment)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM staging)  
) || '''  
FROM staging
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
'''
```

However, i am unable to translate this script in Snowflake (still a beginner on the tech).
Is there any workaround that i can use to have the same result on Snowflake ?

Thanks to all for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

so the dynamic SQL is producing this:

```
select id,
    count_if(segment = 'segment_1') as segment_1,
    count_if(segment = 'segment_2') as segment_2,
    count_if(segment = 'segment_3') as segment_3,
    count_if(segment = 'segment_4') as segment_4,
    count_if(segment = 'segment_5') as segment_5
from staging
group by 1
order by 1;
```

which is we bundle with a CTE for data:

```
with staging(id, segment) as (
    select * from values
    ('ID_A','segment_1'),
    ('ID_A','segment_2'),
    ('ID_B','segment_2'),
    ('ID_B','segment_3'),
    ('ID_B','segment_4'),
    ('ID_B','segment_5'),
    ('ID_C','segment_1'),
    ('ID_D','segment_2'),
    ('ID_D','segment_4')
)
```

produces:

[image]

so there is the "solution if you have a fixed set of columns" but it is dynamic:

so then we wish to build the dynamic version, which can change if in one data run you have different data, so I strongly suggest not using this, plus the performance of double query. But a dynamic SQL generation can be useful to build copy-pasta SQL so, that could be done in which the same way as the bigquery:

firstly now lets make a table:

```
create table staging(id, segment) as (
    select * from values
    ('ID_A','segment_1'),
    ('ID_A','segment_2'),
    ('ID_B','segment_2'),
    ('ID_B','segment_3'),
    ('ID_B','segment_4'),
    ('ID_B','segment_5'),
    ('ID_C','segment_1'),
    ('ID_D','segment_2'),
    ('ID_D','segment_4')
);
```

then

the inner sql is the first clue:

```
SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM staging;
```

then the next layer is building count_if lines, so swapping STRING_AGG to [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg) we can have a basic form:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( segment || ' as ' || segment, ', ' ) within group (ORDER BY segment)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM staging
)
```

[image]

```
SELECT LISTAGG( 'COUNT_IF(segment = ' || segment || ') as ' || segment, ',\n' ) within group (ORDER BY segment)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM staging
)
```

gets us very close:

[image]

but we want those right hand side values to be quoted, so we can use triple quotes `'''`

```
SELECT LISTAGG( 'COUNT_IF(segment = ''' || segment || ''') as ' || segment, ',\n' ) within group (ORDER BY segment)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM staging
)
```

[image]

so now we mash that into some Dynamic SQL block:

```
DECLARE
  rs RESULTSET;
  query VARCHAR;
  col_sql VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  col_sql := (SELECT LISTAGG( 'COUNT_IF(segment = ''' || segment || ''') as ' || segment, ',\n' ) within group (ORDER BY segment) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM staging));
  query := 'SELECT id, ' || col_sql || ' FROM staging GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1'; 
  rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
  RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
```

and we get:

[image]

Comment: Hello Simeon, that's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for your help! The step by step explanation is a big plus.